# Friend within private nested class

Tags: c++, nested, friend

I have two private nested classes that would need to access a private member in another class. I thought about putting the class that needs to access the private member as friend in the accessed class, however I'm getting an error that A::m_nData is private so I can't access it. Anyway of telling the compiler that I need to access the A::m_nData private member within D::DoSomething()?

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

File *A.h*

```
class A
{
    class D;

    public:
        A();
        ~A() {}

    private:
        friend class D;

        int m_nData;
};
```

File *A.cpp:*

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

A::A()
:   m_nData(0)
{
}
```

File *B.h:*

```
#include "A.h"

class B
{
    public:
        B() {}
        ~B() {}

    private:
        class C
        {
            public:
                C(A* pA): m_pA(pA) {}
                virtual ~C() {}
                virtual void DoSomething() {}

            protected:
                A* m_pA;
        };

        class D: public C
        {
            public:
                D(A* pA): C(pA) {}
                virtual ~D() {}
                virtual void DoSomething()
                {
                    m_pA->m_nData++;
                };
        };
};
```

Comment: Why must `C` and `D` be nested inside `B`? What advantage do you perceive by doing that?

Comment: @ildjarn: In the real use-case, A is defining 4 delegates that can be set. B is acting like a manager of A. I had to remove a whole lot of code, but C and D are wrapper that call the callback of A using the A pointer. In the example I've put there, I changed those to an int value instead.

Comment: That doesn't answer why they must be _nested_ classes... Why are they nested inside of `B`?

Comment: Well, since it was code that was only used in the context of B, I didn't see the need to be set outside its scope. There must be a way in C++ to make it work the way it is, no?

Comment: Clearly it's _not_ only used in the context of `B` though, otherwise you wouldn't be posting this question. ;-] Ultimately your best fix here is to rethink your design.

Answer (score 2):

**You need two friendships here.**  One to let `A` know about the private `B::D` and another to let `B::D` access private data in `A`.

Declare (include) class B before declaring class A.

Then in `class B`, add:

```
friend class A;
```

This allows class A to know about the private `B::D`.

Then in `class A`, replace:

```
friend class D;
```

with:

```
friend class B::D;
```

Comment: @KerrekSB: `friend class B::D` doesn't provide access to `B::D`, it allows access from it.  Unless my coffee is failing me this morning.

Comment: @DrewDormann: No, coffee failure is on my side! Comment deleted!

Comment: @DrewDormann: I can't include class B in A.h since I would get recursive inclusion as B.h already include A.h.

Comment: @golbez: In a.cpp, include b.h before a.h.  You'll have to move the DoSomething() definition out of the header, but that's a good practice anyway.  You're almost there.