# Specializing std::hash for private member class

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, unordered-set, stdhash

I have a class (call it `Outer`) which has a private member class (`Inner`). I want to store instances of `Outer::Inner` in unordered standard containers, so I want to specialize `std::hash<Outer::Inner>`.

However, when writing this:

```
namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash<Outer::Inner> {
        std::size_t operator()(const Outer::Inner &arg) const
        {
            return std::hash<int>()(arg.someSpecialProperty);
        }
    };
}
```

the compiler complains:

```
error: 'Inner' is a private member of 'Outer'
            std::size_t operator()(const Outer::Inner &p) const
                                                ^
```

I have tried to make `std::hash` a friend struct by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890747/hash-function-for-user-defined-class-how-to-make-friends), but that didn't work either: the forward declaration of `Outer::Inner` failed with:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'Outer'
```

So how should I proceed (if what I intend to do is possible at all)?

Comment: By refering to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760181/friend-within-private-nested-class it seems like your case is not possible, because you can't add a friendship in std::hash ...

Comment: @AntiClimacus because I am not the one who declared the original `std::hash` template, right?

Comment: this is the reason, yes.

Comment: @AntiClimacus Oh, thanks. Well, that's disappointing. :-( (don't hesitate to write an answer if you feel like that.)

Comment: Can't you just declare `friend struct std::hash<Inner>;` inside `Outer`? (Probably after declaring or defining `Inner`.) And then define your specialisation after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's a private inner type, I assume that you have a `private` or `protected` `std::unordered_map` member in the enclosing class. If that's the case, just write a private inner hash functor and pass it as the third argument of the `std::unordered_map`. It's the easiest solution to your problem, I think.

Comment: Yeah, I finally ended up doing this. Not the prettiest solution, I guess.

Answer (score 9):

Got it ! The solution is to use your own functors, not specialize std::hash.

```
struct A
{
  A() { v.insert(std::make_pair(B(1), 6)); }

private:
  struct B
  {
    B(int i = 0) : m_i(i) { }

    int m_i;
  };

  struct HashB { std::size_t operator()(const B& b) const { return b.m_i; } };
  struct EqualB { bool operator()(const B&b1, const B&b2) const { return b1.m_i == b2.m_i; } };


  std::unordered_map<B, int, HashB, EqualB> v;
};
```